# Grails 1.3.7 to 2.3.4 upgrade "hibernate-3.6.10.6.zip is not a valid plugin"

Tags: grails

I recently upgraded my project from 1.3.7 to 2.3.4. I removed the following from application.properties:

```
plugins.hibernate=1.3.7
plugins.tomcat=1.3.7
```

and added the following to BuildConfig.groovy instead:

```
plugins {
    build ':tomcat:7.0.47'
    runtime ':hibernate:3.6.10.6'
}
```

then I ran `grails upgrade`. After I ran `refresh dependencies` I got the following error:

> ~/.grails/ivy-cache/org.grails.plugins/hibernate/zips/hibernate-3.6.10.6.zip is not a valid plugin

This project uses an internal plugin which has been upgraded to 2.3.4 and depends on the same versions of the hibernate and tomcat plugins. I also tried adding the following to BuildConfig.groovy

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {    
    legacyResolve true
}
```

But it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Try removing the file from your ivy cache and getting it again

Comment: I tried that but it didn't help. Also I tried using maven instead : grails.project.dependency.resolver="maven" . This just changed the error to a different folder : "~/.m2/repository/org/grails/plugins/hibernate/3.6.10.6/hibernate-3.6.10.6.zip is not a valid plugin"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that xerces.jar was in the lib folder causing problems. Removing this fixed the refresh dependencies issue I was having. Note : Simply adding this resource dependency to the BuildConfig.groovy still causes errors... you need to exclude the xml apis like this:

BuildConfig.groovy

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
     dependencies {
          compile("xerces:xercesImpl:2.9.1") {
               excludes 'xml-apis'
          }
     }
}
```